# Narrowing on Tramp Buffers Only When Using helm-buffers-list

Tags: helm, tramp

I'd like to close all Tramp buffers in one fell swoop. Is it possible to narrow on Tramp buffers only when invoking `helm-buffers-list`? I've tried various suggestions offered in Helm Help, but cannot narrow in on all Tramp buffers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using `helm`, but there is `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-buffers`. It closes all remote buffers, including the hidden connection buffers.

Comment: That works, thanks. Do you have `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-buffers` bound to any keys?

Comment: No, none of the Tramp commands is bound to any key.